# React native android Undefined is not function

Tags: android, react-native

**React native android:**

When I am navigating from one screen to next screen

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0,
>   _reactNavigation.StackNavigator)({ SettingScreen: { screen: _settings.default }, HomeScreen: { screen: _Home.default } })')

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Settings from './screens/Settings';
import Home from './screens/Home';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  SettingScreen: { screen: Settings },
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home }
});

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

    render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

Setting.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export class Settings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the Settings screen</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} title="Home"/>
      </View>
    )
  }
};

export default Settings;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the home screen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the updated function like below.

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your App.js to the below.

   *const App = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
   });*

   *export default createAppContainer(App);*
2. Remove the line *export default Settings;*
3. Remove the line *export default Home;*

Answer (score 0):

Please, Try with the below changes.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 {
    SettingScreen: { screen: Settings },
    HomeScreen: { screen: Home }
  }
)
```